# Quit an application while hold some key and click the application in dock

Tags: macos, mac, macos-mojave, macos-highsierra, macos-catalina

Is there any way to quit  a application in dock, while pressing some key and just click it in dock ?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click or Control-click; the first option in the menu is Quit.
You don't need to bring the app to the front to do this.

[image]

Comment: is there any way just pressing a key and click, then quit the app

Comment: If there was, I would have included it in my answer. There is no quicker way. If you don't want to move the mouse that extra ½" then you could just click the app in the dock, which would bring it to the front, then use the regular Cmd/Q.